# User Control RegisterScriptDescriptors Circular Reference

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

Im not sure why I am running into a circular reference when trying to register script descriptors.  Here is my code for the user control:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs eventArguments)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs eventArguments)
    {
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterScriptControl(this);
        base.OnPreRender(eventArguments);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter)
    {
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterScriptDescriptors(this);
        base.Render(htmlWriter);
    }
```

I am getting the exception ( System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'ASP.global_asax'.) on RegisterScriptDescriptors.

Here is my entire Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StockPicker.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I answered it after struggling a bit.  I was using another user control in the control and I was using that control in the GetScriptDescriptors method.  This was causing the circular reference.